# ggplot: plot 4th discrete variable respective of 3rd continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
d <- data.frame(w = runif(3000),
                x = runif(3000),
                y = rnorm(3000),
                z = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 1000))
```

I can plot `w` as a continuous variable with some colour palette; `scale_colour_viridis_c()` does this nicely:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
 geom_point(aes(colour = w)) +
 scale_colour_viridis_c()
```

But say I want to express `w` in terms of `z` too. I can't with the `option` argument in `scale_colour_viridis_c()` because "EXPR must be a length 1 vector".

How can I do this such that there are more than one colour palette used (i.e., `unique(d$z)`)?

Comment: Do you want to basically have 3 sets of points with 3 different colour palettes?  Typically you wouldn't want to mix colour scales like this, as it's likely to be less clear, rather than more.  Perhaps `shape=factor(z)` in your `aes()` call would be better?

Comment: `colour=interaction(w, z)`.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am looking for 3 colour palettes defined by `z` where each palette's gradient is defined by `w`. Unfortunately `(group = z)` does not work.

Comment: `option` takes only specific values:
A character string indicating the colormap option to use. Four options are available: "magma" (or "A"), "inferno" (or "B"), "plasma" (or "C"), "viridis" (or "D", the default option) and "cividis" (or "E"). - i.e. it needs to be one of those, not a vector of many.

Comment: Thanks, Limey. Unfortunately "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

Comment: @Paul, yes indeed, hence the error "EXPR must be a length 1 vector".

Comment: Yes.  Indeed.  That's because of your use of `scale_colour_viridis_c()`.  Delete that and you will (eventually) get a plot.  Though it will be useless because of the number of categories in the interaction given by your sample data.  Even with a data.frame with 99 rows, the plot is incomprehensible.  A more sensible test dataset will allow you to customise to your needs.

Comment: If you're insistent on combining multiple colour scales, which I discourage, look into the `ggnewscale` package which allows this interaction.

Answer (score 1):

One option to have multiple color (or ...) scales for the same aesthetic would be the `ggnewscale` package which TBMK requires to split your data by `z` and use multiple layers. To make this a bit easier I use `purrr::imap` to create the layers for each `z`:

```r
set.seed(123)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

d_split <- split(d, d$z)

limits <- range(d$w)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x, y)) +
  purrr::imap(d_split, function(x, y) {
    list(
      geom_point(aes(colour = w), data = x),
      scale_colour_viridis_c(option = y, limits = limits),
      new_scale_colour()
    )
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the starting point I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your sample data slightly so that the plot is at least vaguely sensible:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(w = round(runif(99), 1),
                x = runif(99),
                y = round(rnorm(99), 1),
                z = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 33))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = interaction(w, z)))
```

`interaction()` creates a discrete categorisation so you can't use `scale_colour_viridis_c()`.

[image]